# How do I output a plain text string to a variable on Anypoint Platform with Dataweave?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I feel like I'm losing my mind because I can't figure out how to do something as simple as iterate over an object, concatenate a plain text string, and output the result to a variable. Here is something similar I've done which works fine:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var promptParams = attributes.queryParams filterObject($$ startsWith "PROMPT") orderBy($$)
---
{
RESULT: {
    Prompts: 
        promptParams mapObject(promptValue, promptName, index) -> {
            PROMPT: {
                UniquePromptName: promptName,
                FieldValue: promptValue
                }
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case I filter the url query string parameters to get only the ones I want, then I iterate over those and construct the xml output. The problem I'm having is that if I try to do the same thing but output a plain text string to a variable, I can't get anything to work.

Basically what I want is to go from this input:

```
https://example.com?PROMPT1=foo&PROMPT2=bar&PROMPT3=lorem&PROMPT4=ipsum&utm_source=Dolor&utm_campaign=SitAmet
```

to this output stored in a flow variable:

```
foo!bar!lorem!ipsum
```

I must be missing something basic because it can't be that hard to accomplish this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var promptParams = attributes.queryParams filterObject($$ startsWith "PROMPT")
---
promptParams pluck($) reduce ($$ ++ "!" ++ $)
```

Output:
`foo!bar!lorem!ipsum`

You asked for text plain, but I would recommend application/java if you are usign the variable inside the flow.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var promptParams = (((payload.message splitBy "?")[1]) splitBy "&") //stored url //in payload.message
---
promptParams map {
    a: ($ splitBy "=")[1]
}.a joinBy "!"
```

Comment: I don't think DataWeave should split the query parameters when the HTTP connector already provides them in the queryParams attribute and probably taking care of encoding issues.

Comment: Did that since I was not using query params and instead a string representing a url.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `pluck` and `joinBy` and just make sure that you have the target set to a variable if you are using the transform message component.

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" >
    <ee:variables >
        <ee:set-variable variableName="promptAttributes" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
(attributes.queryParams[?($$ startsWith "PROMPT")] pluck $) joinBy "!"]] </ee:set-variable>
    </ee:variables>
</ee:transform>
```

Comment: This is the most succinct and is how I would do it.